# Spring boot - Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to create a spring boot application who instanciate the DAO from another project based on hibernate 4.

The problem is that Spring boot want to use a method from Hibernate 5 and I don't know from where.

Here is the failed message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)

The following method did not exist:

    org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;

The method's class, org.hibernate.Session, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/x/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.30.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/Session.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.hibernate.Session: file:/C:/Users/x/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.30.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.Session


Process finished with exit code 0
```

And here is the pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">



    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <name>Test</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It has been really complicated for me to understand this king of old system using an applicationContext but here is the spring-hibernate-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

This configuration file actually works with J2E projects so I don't understand how I can exclude Hibernate 5 from the configuration, because it never called.

I could try to remove these dependencies from the classpath but when I do that, the API is broken and I have to start from the beginning.

Do you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: You can't mix Hibernate 4 and 5 together in the same project. The external DAO will need to be upgraded to Hibernate 5 first. It seems that Hibernate 5 is already [4 years old](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/) so time to upgrade probably.

Comment: agree with you but in this project, I don't want to use hibernate 5 and I absolutely don't know from where it's instanciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally, I've removed all hibernates 5 external librairies and add manually the same under hibernate 4. It's a little bit long but I can finally continue the configuration. :)

Comment: The fact that you can even use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` is a bit troublesome. That shouldn't be available with Spring Boot 2.4.5, which means you are mixing different versions of modules from Spring / Spring Boot which eventually will lead to other weird to debug issues. Also you are already mixing 2.4.0 and 2.4.5 versions of Spring boot. So something is eventually going to blow up.

Comment: Yes, you're true for the different version of spring boot. I've corrected this. To continue to use hibernate 4, I've created an HibernateFactory who will get the DAO and the hibernate configuration from another application. So, in fact, I don't really use hibernate 4 inside the Spring Boot project but I need hibernate 4 external librairies to get my xml config files recognized.